# jquery mobile, what is the proper way to have content inside a list list view-inset content block?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, styling

Installed a bare jquery with basic theme. Several websites build with jquery mobile have the content inside a inset listview element. But If i Try this im unable to get any decent styling of headings bold or italics.

Whats the right way to get the content inside a inset element like in below screenshow but have decent basic formatting like h1,h2,etc?: (inset content ):

[image]

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
    <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-inset ui-shadow">
        <li>

            Headings not correctly styled

            <h1>test</h1>
            <h2>test</h2>
            <h3>test</h3>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Using this:

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li>
            <h3>test</h3>
            <h1>h1</h1>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>jQuery Team</h3>
            <p><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
            <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of <strong>sponsors</strong> and speakers.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Does list some content like in my screenshot with formatting but everytying outside a

is not formatted + it strips the text length if it gets to long .. :(

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-inset.html right click, view source. Gives examples

Comment: Thx for pointing to that section, totally right I messed up with some styling and the IOS simulator also doesent seem to fully support stuff like fixed headers